# Pandas series messing up with booleans

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series

I have this python code using a dataframe termed data, with two columns/series labelled 'Id' and 'Open', filled with ints and booleans.
But the following code

```
print(data['Id'][0])
print(data['Id'][1])
print(data['Open'][0])
print(data['Open'][1]) 
print(data['Id'][0]!=0)
print(data['Id'][1]!=0)
print(data['Open'][0]!=0)
print(data['Open'][1]!=0)
```

gives me that output:

```
0    0
0    1
Name: Id, dtype: int64
1    0
1    2
Name: Id, dtype: int64
0    1
0    1
Name: Open, dtype: float64
1    1
1    1
Name: Open, dtype: float64
0    False
0     True
Name: Id, dtype: bool
1    False
1     True
Name: Id, dtype: bool
0    True
0    True
Name: Open, dtype: bool
1    True
1    True
Name: Open, dtype: bool
```

Given that http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html
describe columns as series, I should be able to use data['Id'][0] and read an int and result of its comparison to zero.
But I read instead these silly couples of numbers under an index, while I am positive that I have no tuples in my df (I parsed it from two csv which contained only ints or 0/1).
So where is my error? I tried iloc and loc too, but result is the same.
So what did I misunderstood from pandas docs, please?

Subsidiary question: I printed that because I had a problem with my boolean indexing, as I wanted to select my data with data=data[data[id]>0 & data['open']==1], but it keeps failing. I tried to make the boolean before with 
list comprehensions

```
booleanopen=[True if i==1 else False for i in data['Id']] 
booleanId=[True if i>01 else False for i in data['Id']] 
booleanand=booleanopen&booleanId
data=data[booleanand]
```

But it crashes continuously without traceback or error message. The computer just get stuck for hours.
(I think I can't use  instead:

```
booleanopen=[true for i==1 in data['Id']]
```

since it would give an array full of true of length equals to the number of 1, contrary to the previous one)

Answer (score 1):

> I should be able to use data['Id'][0] and read an int

`data["Id"][0]` means "take the column called Id, and access the portion of the data associated with the index 0".  If you have multiple rows with the same index, pandas will return them.  For example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Id": pd.Series([10,20,30], index=[0,0,1])})
>>> df["Id"][0]
0    10
0    20
Name: Id, dtype: int64
>>> df["Id"][1]
30
```

While you didn't show your frame for some reason, I'm pretty sure this is what's going on.  You'll have to look into how it's being constructed to figure out why (you can always do `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` to return to a 'normal' index if the index isn't currently containing any information anyway.)

As for the separate question, "but it keeps failing" isn't much use as an error report, but possibly you just didn't use parentheses as the docs demonstrate:

```
>>> df["Open"] = [1,2,1]
>>> df[(df["Id"] > 20) & (df["Open"] == 1)]
   Id  Open
1  30     1
>>> df.loc[(df["Id"] > 20) & (df["Open"] == 1)]
   Id  Open
1  30     1
```

Comment: It keeps failing meant that boolean evaluation was incorrect, sorry. As for the index, I am not so sure what is happening, because each column is coming from different sources of preprocessing. But I will investigate at that level. Problem being, while pandas is intented to be simple, index management is very messy and some things happen seemingly out of nowhere because of that. While specifying explicitely types, I also had all sorts of problems -_-. Thanks anyway. Lots of debugging and tracing forward to do, I guess.

Comment: I investigated a bit more, writing the file as a csv. But it appears to have only one field per column. Actually I think that this is the index which is presented here as a tuple.
Do I have to use the parenthesis in your second answer if I use a list comprehension too, to enclose the boolean evaluation?

Comment: @AndoJurai: you're going to need to present a [mcve] at this point; nothing either of us have shown looks like a tuple.

Comment: Well when i change the index value for 10 and 21 I have output like;
10    0
10    1
Name: Id, dtype: int64
21    0
21    22
Name: Id, dtype: int64.
So it occured to me that it was a tuple with an index number. It is actually more stupid than that; I concatenated to df and their index was mixed up. Foolish me!